# macOS asking to install supplemental 10.15 Catalina update inspite of running the latest stable release of Catalina

Tags: macos, software-update, catalina

I am currently running Catalina 10.15 but the software update module still shows that I need to install the supplemental update,

Now, the issue is, in order to get rid of this update notification I clicked on install now; but, each and every time I click on the install button, the supplemental update gets installed - like the mac restarts and all - but after everything is complete and the mac reboots,

Once again, the update notification pops up, asking me to update once again!

[image]